# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent{ act=android.intent.action.SENDTO (has extras) }

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-intent

Most intents are not working even when i used the same code as in Android Documentation. I don't know what I'm missing. I tried making another app and try again, didn't work. I keep getting "android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent{ act=android.intent.action.SENDTO (has extras) }" this in catch.

This is Main activity and the only activity in the app.

```
package com.example.practice4;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String [] questions = {"Java is a person.", "Java was introduced in 1233.", "Java was created using Python.", "Java has abstract classes.", "Java supports interface."};
    private boolean[] answers = {false, false, false, true, true};
    private int index = 0;
    private int score = 0;

    Button yes, no, share;
    TextView question;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        yes = findViewById(R.id.yes);
        no = findViewById(R.id.no);
        share = findViewById(R.id.share);
        question = findViewById(R.id.question);
        question.setText(questions[index]);

        share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I scored "+score+"/"+questions.length+" in my java quiz");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "App chal gyi bc");
                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                }catch (ActivityNotFoundException e){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    question.setText(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        yes.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(index<questions.length) {
                    if(answers[index]){
                        score++;
                    }
                    if(index+1<questions.length){
                        question.setText(questions[++index]);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You scored "+score+"/5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(index<questions.length) {
                    if(!answers[index]){
                        score++;
                    }
                    if(index+1<questions.length){
                        question.setText(questions[++index]);
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You scored "+score+"/5", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

This is the xml of the Main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Java Quiz"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="219dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/java"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="75dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1. Java was introduced in 1823."
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.168" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="True"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/no"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/no"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="False"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/yes"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/question"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="102dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="Share"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.948"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/yes"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.794"
        app:shapeAppearance="@style/Widget.Material3.CircularProgressIndicator.Medium" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Intent.ACTION_SENDTO needs data set not extras. You can use Intent.ACTION_SEND and user would get choice to select application they want to send through. If you explicitly want to share with particular app you can set that using setPackage